# Scrollable unordered list with hotkeys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build an unordered list i HTML where the user is able to "select" the listitems (basically they're just copied into a div when clicked on)

While this is quite easy to achieve, the user should also be able to press a key on their keyboard to make the list scroll to the first listitem which first letter is equal to the letter of the pressed key.

Image for reference:

[image]

Let's pretend that there are 200+ listitems in the above list and I want to "search"/go to **airplane**, I hit **A** on my keyboard and the list scrolls to the first instance in the list starting with "a"

I was wondering if there's already any jQuery plugins out there, that does exactly this? :-) Been searching around, but without any luck at all. If not, I'd of course have to write it myself, I'm just not sure on how to actually capture the letter the user presses.

Any hint on how to create this is greatly appreciated! :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you want [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: If you have `tank`, `trolley`, and `racecar`, what should happen when `tr` is typed?

Comment: Please show us the HTML for your scrollable list.  It's not hard to grab key events and act on them, but we'd need to see what your HTML looks like.

Comment: @Vega: I suppose it could be modified to the needs, yes :) Thanks!

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo: in that case it should scroll to the first instance in the list which starts with "t" and after "r" is pressed it should scroll to the first instance in the list which starts with "r" :) It should only scroll on a single key/letter

Comment: @jfriend00: I honestly haven't made any html for it yet since I was kinda hoping that there was some kind of plugin already written for this purpose. However, a scrollable ul isn't that hard to make after all ;)

Comment: @bomortensen Is ui auto-complete is not what you want?

Comment: @Vega: Both yes and no ;) the list should be displayed at all times so the user is able to manually scroll through the list items and select them. However they should also be able to just press a key, i.e. "C" and the list should scroll to first list item which starts with "C" - if that makes sense? :P

Comment: In your example the list is not alphabetized (but it might not matter). So does pressing 'r' repeatedly jump you to the next 'r' items, like 'Rolls-Royce,' 'Rad bike', etc. (otherwise it's rather pointless with an unordered list)? Or do we assume the list will be ordered?

Comment: Well capturing the keystrokes is a few lines of code.  Most of the code is comparing the keys to the text you have in your HTML and manipulating the data to show a match and most of that code is navigating whatever HTML you have.  That's why I asked to see your HTML.

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo yeah, that kind of behavior would also be cool! :) definitely! By the way, thanks to you all for your great input so far.

Comment: @bomortensen I'm trying to get something working, but I'll ask a basic question because I'm stuck. Are you using a `<select>` box or something else?

Comment: @bomortensen Even better, would be to see a piece of code showing what you are looking after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my code to override the default browser behavior for `<select multiple="multiple">`. My conclusion is that it's a bad idea to try doing this, because of how each browser treats input and jQuery code.

I suggest Mr. Mortensen to find a UI widget or replacement such as checkboxes inside a scrolling div that will provide more predictable behavior, then apply my code functionality to that choice. There are various options I stuck with the generic `<select>` code:

**The inconsistencies:** I was surprised *Opera* worked just like I wanted. *IE 7* just ignored my code. *Chrome*: When a key is pressed to select an item out of view, it will scroll up, but not down. Puzzling. *Firefox*: I cannot have `event.preventDefault()` working. So my whole code is ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtLF2/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var indices = {};
        var count = 1;

        // build a dictionary matching first letters to indices of where
        // they were found
        $("#mylist option").each(function() {
          var letter = $(this).text().charAt(0).toLowerCase();
          if(!indices[letter]) {
            indices[letter] = [];
          }
          indices[letter].push(count);
          count++;
        });

        var lastletter = "";
        var lastindex = -1;

        $("#mylist").on('keypress', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var pressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
          if(pressed == lastletter) {
            lastindex == indices[lastletter].length - 1 ? lastindex = 0 : lastindex++;
          }
          else {
            lastletter = pressed;
            lastindex = 0;
          }

          if(indices[lastletter]) {
            var target = indices[lastletter][lastindex];
            $("#mylist option:selected").each(function() {
              $(this).removeAttr("selected");
            });
            $("#mylist option:nth-child(" + target + ")").attr("selected", "selected");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mylist" multiple="multiple" size="5">
      <option value="1">Tank</option>
      <option value="2">APC</option>
      <option>Mini tricycle</option>
      <option>Bike</option>
      <option>Megatank</option>
      <option>Brawler</option>
      <option>Trailer</option>
      <option>Md Tank</option>
      <option>Armored van</option>
      <option>War Machine</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mia, thank you SO much! That's just awesome stuff right there :-) I've spent the last few days with talking to the project manager about this and it seems like they want to just with a regular AutoComplete, after all.. Sigh! :/ I'm definitely going to save your code for later use! Thanks again :)

Comment: @bomortensen I think you're lucky you can use a plain old Autocomplete, because when I say my code doesn't run the same on different browsers, I say it's a bug :| Well, thanks for accepting and taking me over 1,000 rep :)